# Gulp and Webpack stream not working with Imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, gulp

Bear with me! I'm a designer.

I'm trying to get ES6 imports working with Gulp and WebStream. TRied dozens of things but no joy!

It's producing the bundle file ok, but there is a tonne of webpack_require stuff at the top of file. like:  **webpack_require**.d(**webpack_exports**, "AnimationUtils", function() { return AnimationUtils; });\n/* harmony export (binding) */ **webpack_require**.d

Below that in the bundle file it looks like the Three.js code, which is exactly what i'm looking for.

.js file:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

Relevant Gulp:

```
function processJS(){
  return src('site/web/assets/source/*.js')
      .pipe(webpack({
          mode: 'development',
          output: {
              filename: 'bundle.js'
          }
      }))
      .pipe(babel({ presets: ['@babel/env'], compact: false, }))
      .pipe(dest('site/web/assets/js/'));
}
```

Package.json:

```
 {
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp": "latest",
    "gulp-cached": "latest",
    "gulp-notify": "latest",
    "gulp-plumber": "latest",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "latest",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
    "sass": "latest",
    "webpack-stream": "^6.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-mode": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-gsap": "^3.0.0",
    "three": "^0.131.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks for looking, help greatly appreciated.